# No space between unicode character and next character

Tags: r, unicode

Say I want to print degrees Celsius in R, I could use unicode like this:

```
print("\U00B0 C")
[1] "° C"
```

Note, however, the space. I don't want it there, so I remove it:

```
print("\U00B0C")
[1] "ଌ"
```

Clearly, `00B0C` is unicode for a very different character! Presumably, if there is any alphanumeric after the unicode it will, understandably, just interpret that as part of the unicode. I could use paste or something similar like this:

```
print(paste("\U00B0","C", sep = ""))
[1] "°C"
```

but is there a more concise way to indicate that the unicode is finished and I'm now just using regular letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lower case `u`:

```
print("\u00B0C")
```

Comment: Brilliant! And why does that work? Does a lowercase u indicate that just the next 4 alphanumeric characters will be unicode?

Comment: I believe so.  This is from the documentation for `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode()`:  

    "Moreover, the function understands the following ones: \uXXXX (4 
    hex digits), \UXXXXXXXX (8 hex digits), \xXX (1-2 hex digits), ..."